# Использование ф-ции из DLL написанной на Си в проекте на С#

Tags: c#

Имеется DLL-ка , в проекте на С# WinForm  использую функции из этой DLL-ки
в настройках проекта ставлю "Разрешить небезопасный код".

Потом  в  public partial class Form1 : Form

```
  struct hcSqlParmT
    {
        public ushort size;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe struct hcSqlDstInfoT // Структура "Информация о колонках результата"
    {
        public int aliasno;
        public int fieldno;
        public int type;
        public uint len;
        public uint off;
        public fixed char coder[32];
        public fixed char fname[32];
        public int func;
        public fixed char asname[32];
        public int key;
        public int resno;
    };

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static extern int hcSqlInit(IntPtr dummy);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static extern int hcSqlCheckInit();

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlAllocConnect(out int pdb);
    //static unsafe extern int hcSqlAllocConnect(int* pdb);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlConnect(int pdb, string server, string login, string password);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlAllocStmt(int pdb, int* pOper);// Создать оператор

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlSetStmtAttr(int pOper, uint option, void* pValue, uint size);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlExecDirect(int pOper, string strSQL);// Выполняем SQLзапрос

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlNumResultCols(int pOper, int* pCol);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlRowCount(int pOper, long* pStr);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlOpenResults(int pOper, uint* pRecSize);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlGetStmtAttr(int pOper, uint option, int pos, [In, Out]hcSqlDstInfoT[] pValue, uint size, uint* cnt);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlReadResults(int pOper, long gStart, byte[] pBuf, uint wBufSize, uint* cnt);

    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlCloseResults(int pOper); // Закрытие доступа к результатам
    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlFreeConnect(int pdb); // Освободить соединение
    [DllImport("hscli.dll")]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlDone();// Завершение работы
```

на кнопку вешаю вот такой код

```
unsafe private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int err = -300000;// код ошибки заведомо не существующий

        int pdb = 0;
        int pOper = 0; // идетификатор оператора
        int pCol = 0; // кол-во колонок
        long pStr = 0; // кол-во строк
        uint pRecSize = 0; // размер записи
        uint cntOp = 0; // сколько байтов записали в буфер
        long gStart = 0; // с какой записи начинаем читать 

        if ((err = hcSqlInit(IntPtr.Zero)) != 0) { return; } // Инициализация клиентской части 
        textBox5.AppendText("Инициализация клиентской части err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlCheckInit(); // Проверка завершения инициализации
        textBox5.AppendText("Проверка завершения инициализации err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlAllocConnect(out pdb); // Создать соединение
        textBox5.AppendText("Создать соединение err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
        textBox5.AppendText("соединение pdb = " + pdb.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlConnect(pdb, textBox1.Text.ToString(), textBox2.Text.ToString(), textBox3.Text.ToString()); //Установить связь с СУБД
        textBox5.AppendText("Установить связь с СУБД err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlAllocStmt(pdb, &pOper); // Создать оператор
        textBox5.AppendText("Создать оператор err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
        textBox5.AppendText("оператор pOper = " + pOper.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlSetStmtAttr(pOper, 1001, (void*)1, 0); // ф-ция "Изменение параметров оператора"
        textBox5.AppendText("ф-ция Изменение параметров оператора err = " + pOper.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlExecDirect(pOper, textBox4.Text.ToString()); // Выполняем SQLзапрос
        textBox5.AppendText("Выполняем SQLзапрос = " + pOper.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlNumResultCols(pOper, &pCol); // Получить кол-во колонок результата
        textBox5.AppendText("кол-во колонок = " + pCol.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlRowCount(pOper, &pStr); // Получить кол-во строк результата
        textBox5.AppendText("кол-во строк = " + pStr.ToString() + "\r\n");
        err = hcSqlOpenResults(pOper, &pRecSize); // Открытие результатов для чтения
        textBox5.AppendText("размер записи = " + pRecSize.ToString() + "\r\n");

        hcSqlDstInfoT[] infCol = new hcSqlDstInfoT[pCol]; // Структура "Информация о колонках результата" 
        err = hcSqlGetStmtAttr(pOper, 107, 0, infCol, (uint)pCol * 128, &cntOp);// Получить информацию об операторе

        uint cntOut = 0;
        byte[] bufOut = new byte[pRecSize * pStr]; // Адрес буфера для присылаемых записей.
        err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, 0, bufOut, pRecSize * (uint)pStr, &cntOut );// Чтение результатов

        // byte p = bufOut; 

            for (long i = 0; i < pStr; i++)// идем по строкам
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pCol; ++j)// идем по колонкам
                {
                    switch (infCol[j].type)// в зависимости от типа колонки преобразовываем в соответствующий тип
                    {
                        case 0: // 0 Массив символов длиной не более заданной 
                                //string s(p, infCol[j].len);
                            textBox5.AppendText(infCol[j].type + " ");
                            break;
                        case 8:  
                             textBox5.AppendText(infCol[j].type + " ");
                        break;
                     }
                    // p += infCol[j].len;
                }
                textBox5.AppendText("\r\n");
            }
            hcSqlCloseResults(pOper); // Закрытие доступа к результатам
            hcSqlFreeConnect(pdb); // Освободить соединение
            hcSqlDone(); // Завершение работы

 }
```

и вот во  время выполнения останавливается на этой функции
err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, 0, bufOut, pRecSize * (uint)pStr, &cntOut );// Чтение результатов

ошибка

> Цитата
>   Помощник отладки управляемого кода "PInvokeStackImbalance" обнаружил неполадку в "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ComHyTech\ComHyTech\bin\Debug\ComHyTech.vshost.exe". Дополнительные сведения: Вызов функции PInvoke "ComHyTech!ComHyTech.Form1::hcSqlReadResults" разбалансировал стек. Вероятно, это вызвано тем, что управляемая сигнатура PInvoke не совпадает с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой. Убедитесь, что соглашение о вызовах и параметры сигнатуры PInvoke совпадают с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой.

помогите в чем проблема, в дебаге смотрю  буфер bufOut создается нужного размера

Comment: Очевидно, у вас неправильные сигнатуры P/Invoke. Откуда вы из взяли?

Comment: Я не пойму о чем речь, это же и есть ошибка.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю ваш комментарий так, что сигнатуры вы ниоткуда не взяли, а придумали сами?

Comment: СУБД HyTech? Строки .NET являются UTF-16, в то время как в API этой СУБД однобайтовый char. Нужно везде указать `CharSet.Ansi` для начала.

Comment: "что сигнатуры вы ниоткуда не взяли, а придумали сами?"  какие сигнатуры что такое сигнатуры ?

Comment: то  что "Строки .NET являются UTF-16, в то время как в API этой СУБД однобайтовый char  , "    -    это  я в курсе ,  только  не могу понять куда воткнуть  "Нужно везде указать CharSet.Ansi для начала."   ,    а главное не могу понять   зачем ?????

Comment: Ну, откуда у вас взялось объявление `static unsafe extern int hcSqlSetStmtAttr(int pOper, uint option, void* pValue, uint size);`?

Comment: из тех документации , http://hytechdb.ru/index.php?s=docs&ru=V25/hscli/txt_func.htm    к  этой  DLL-ке

Comment: я не знаю в каком виде подать буфер,   на  С++  я сделал программу к этой DLL-ке ,   я  использовал char*

Comment: в документации  void *pBuf

Comment: вот как это у меня выглядит на С/С++ https://github.com/vovakms

Comment: возможно ли в C#  передать char*

Answer (score 0):

```
     [DllImport("hscli.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] //, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl   |   ,  EntryPoint="hcSqlReadResults" ,CharSet=CharSet.Auto , SetLastError=true
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlReadResults(int pOper, int gStart,  byte[] bufOut , uint wBufSize, out uint   cntOut);
    int gStart    = 0;                           // с какой записи начинаем читать 
        uint wBufSize = pRecSize * (uint)pStr ;      // задаем размер сколько прочитать
        byte[] bufOut = new byte[(int)wBufSize]  ;   // буфер для результата 
        uint cntOut  ;                               // сколько записали в буфер 
        err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, gStart, bufOut, wBufSize, out cntOut); // Чтение результатов
        textBox_Copy3.AppendText("Чтение результатов  err  = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
```